# Split PHP loop into 2 lists

Tags: php, html-lists

I have built the following function, but is it possible to get it to split my lists from one into more so I can have a maximum of 8 `<li>`'s per `<ul>`?

```
function buildProductsMenu($base) {

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM tbl_category";
    $result     = dbQuery($sql);
    while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
    echo "<ul>";        
        echo "<li class='title'>$row[cat_name]</li>";
            $sqlProd = "SELECT *
                FROM tbl_product WHERE cat_id = $row[cat_id]";
            $resultProd     = dbQuery($sqlProd);
            while ($rowProd = dbFetchAssoc($resultProd)) {
                extract($rowProd);
                echo "<li><a href='".$base."products/".strtolower($row['cat_name'])."/".strtolower($pd_name)."'>".$pd_name."</a></li>";
            }       
    echo "</ul>";               
    }
}
```

**Went with jurgemaister Solution**

```
function buildProductsMenu($base) {

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM tbl_category";
    $result     = dbQuery($sql);
    while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
        echo "<ul>";        
        echo "<li class='title'>$row[cat_name]</li>";
        $sqlProd = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE cat_id = $row[cat_id]";
        $resultProd     = dbQuery($sqlProd);
        $counter = 1;
        while ($rowProd = dbFetchAssoc($resultProd)) {
            extract($rowProd);
            if($counter % 12 == 0) {
                $counter = 1;
                echo "</ul><ul style='margin-top:25px;'>";
            }
            echo "<li><a href='".$base."products/".strtolower($row['cat_name'])."/".strtolower($pd_name)."'>".$pd_name."</a></li>";
            $counter++;
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a counter, and when that counter reaches 8, you start a new `ul`.

```
$counter = 1;
while ($rowProd = dbFetchAssoc($resultProd)) {
    extract($rowProd);

    if($counter % 8 == 0) {
        $counter = 1;
        echo "</ul><ul>";
    }

    echo "<li><a href='".$base."products/".strtolower($row['cat_name'])."/".strtolower($pd_name)."'>".$pd_name."</a></li>";
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! changed it to 12 and added a margin top. Check my edit :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay, instead of echoing the LIs right from the function I suggest you add them all to an array, once things are in an array, its always easier to manage.

Use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) on the final array of LIs and it will split it into groups of eight.

Comment: Then you should also use `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc` See: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Don't know if the used `dbFetchAssoc` is a wrapper to the mysql function but it would be even better to use mysqli and the fetch_array function: http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php