# splitting links in multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, split

I've a menu panel with a dynamic number of links inside it.

The height of that panel has a fixed height (that can change) and I want to calculate how many link elements can fit in that height. When the maximum number of links is reached, I would like the link list to clear itself and split in 3 cols called `.left`, `.center` and `.right`. This happens only in the panel where the links number exceed the available height.

first part of links must be in `.left`, exceeding links then should move to `.center` and (eventually) occupy `.right` as well

here's my html structure

```
<div class="right-menu-panel" style="height:250px">
  <div class="secondary-nav">
    <div class="menu-element">
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-element">
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>

      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>

      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>

      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-element">
      <a href="" class="secondary-menu-link">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in this case the javascript should take action only in the second `<div class="menu-element">` which has 14 links inside it.

and I've started with this JS but I'm stuck here:

```
var menuHeight = $(".right-menu-panel").outerHeight();
var menuItems = Math.max.apply(null, $('.secondary-nav > div').map(function() {
  return $(this).children().length;
}).get());
```

this js let me know which panel has the highest number of div links..

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ea670fh/2/

I'm stuck to this, I don't know how to proceed. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

I've seen this question: [One UL list split into multi columns with fixed height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140864/one-ul-list-split-into-multi-columns-with-fixed-height) but css is not an option for me (IE8 support).

thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. count maximum links in single column
2. exceed links, move to next column

data-prepend: it's ID of a next column to prepend links when links exceed)

```
$.each(indexer, function(idx, elem) {
    var prepend = $(menuElements[elem]).attr('data-prepend');
    if ($(menuElements[elem]).children().length > maxItems) {
        var items = $(menuElements[elem]).children().slice(maxItems).detach();
        $('#' + prepend).prepend(items);
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/q5frqrds/